# PHP Julian date converter algorithms

Tags: php, algorithm, date, calendar, julian-date

Algorithms for the following:

JD 1099114.5

PHP: 3 Mar -1704 12:00:00 (PHP Internal convertor)

```
echo jdtogregorian($int_jd);
```

FLN: 0 Mar -1703 12:00:00 (Fliegel-Van Flandern)

```
function jd_to_gd_fln ($J) {
   $p = $J + 68569;
   $q = floor(4*$p/146097);
   $r = floor($p - (146097*$q + 3)/4);
   $s = floor(4000*($r+1)/1461001);
   $t = floor($r - (1461*$s/4) + 31);
   $u = floor(80*$t/2447);
   $v = floor($u/11);

     $Y = floor(100*($q-49)+$s+$v);
     $M = floor($u + 2 - 12*$v);
     $D = floor($t - 2447*$u/80);

return "$M/$D/$Y";

}
```

MEU: 18 Mar -1703 12:00:00 (Jean Meeus "Astronomical Algorithms, 2nd ed., corrected)

```
function jd_to_greg_meeus($julian) { 
    $Z = intval($J+0.5); 
 $F = ($J+0.5)-$Z;



  if ($Z < 2299161) {$A = $Z;}
   if ($Z >= 2299161) {
        $alpha = floor(($Z-1867216.25)/36524.25);
         $A = $Z + 1 + $alpha - floor($alpha/4);
         }


         $B = $A + 1524;
         $C = floor( ($B-122.1)/365.25);
         $D = floor( 365.25*$C );
         $E = floor( ($B-$D)/30.6001 );


     $day = floor($B - $D - floor(30.6001*$E)); 

if ($E < 13.5) {   $month = $E - 1;}
if ($E > 13.5) {   $month = $E - 13;}
if ($month > 2.5) {  $year = $C - 4716; }
if ($month < 2.5) {  $year = $C - 4715; }



    return "$month/$day/$year";
}
```

RICH: 4 Mar -1703 12:00:00 (Richards in Explanatory Supplement 3rd Ed.)

```
function jd_to_gd_rchrds ($J) {
$y=4716;    
$v=3;
$j=1401;    
$u=5;
$m=2;   
$s=153;
$n=12;  
$w=2;
$r=4;   
$B=274277;
$p=1461;    
$C=-38;

$f = $J + $j + (((4 * $J + $B) / 146097) * 3) / 4 + $C;


$e = $r * $f + $v;
$g = ($e % $p) / $r;
$h = $u * $g + $w;
$D = floor((($h%$s)) / $u + 1);
$M = floor((($h / $s + $m) % $n) + 1);
$Y = floor(($e / $p) - $y + ($n + $m - $M) / $n);

return "$M/$D/$Y"; 
}
```

Each Algorithm has its issues.

What am I doing wrong with the code?

For reference test data should include:

- JD: 2399301.5
- JD: 1721420
- JD: 1721425
- JD: 1721426
- JD: 2422444
- JD: 2222444

Meeus assumes that there is a Gregorian year 0, even if this is astronomically correct, it makes little sense from a calendrical perspective.  Technically then all the results to convert into Gregorian dates are just wrong? Calendrically speaking if there is no 0 but astronomically speaking there is a 0 how does that translate into the same date?

Comment: Starting with the jdtogregorian function, for either 1099114 or 1099114.5 it actually returns "3/3/-1704". @Danny F has interpreted this as "3 Mar 1704 B.C.E. 12:00:00". The PHP documentation is inadequate, so experimentation with JD and proleptic Gregorian calendar date pairs from reliable sources is required to interpret the meaning of the string returned by the PHP function. Similarly all the other return strings must be interpreted in terms of the documentation of the algorithm used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not look at the Fliegel-Van Flandern algorithm. I tested the remaining algorithm for the test cases Danny F requested, and added the last noon the Julian calendar was observed in Rome (JD 2299160) and the first noon of the Gregorian calendar in Rome (JD 2299161). For non-integer Julian days, I only used the Meeus algorithm since that's the only one that says it supports non-integers.

The internal algorithm was correct, when you allow for considering year 0 to not exist, and it always converts to Gregorian. The Meeus algorithm is correct, when you allow for it assuming the existence of year 0, and converting to Julian for October 4, 1582 and earlier, and to Gregorian for dates after that.

The Richards algorithm required corrections. Rather than using the floor function at certain points, I used the intdiv function in place of every "/" operator, which more closely follows Richard's description of the algorithm. After these corrections, the test cases were successful. (Richards considers the year 0 to exist and always converts to Gregorian.)

```
function jd_to_gd_rchrds ($J) {
$y=4716;    
$v=3;
$j=1401;    
$u=5;
$m=2;   
$s=153;
$n=12;  
$w=2;
$r=4;   
$B=274277;
$p=1461;    
$C=-38;

$f = $J + $j + intdiv(intdiv(4 * $J + $B,146097) * 3,4) + $C;

$e = $r * $f + $v;
$g = intdiv(($e % $p) , $r);

$h = $u * $g + $w;
$D = intdiv((($h%$s)) , $u) + 1;
$M = ((intdiv($h , $s) + $m) % $n) + 1;
$Y = intdiv($e , $p) - $y + intdiv($n + $m - $M,$n);

return "$M/$D/$Y"; 
}
```

Testcase results:

```
Julian day PHP internal Meeus      Richards
0          0/0/0        1/1/-4712  11/24/-4713
1          11/25/-4714  1/2/-4712  11/25/-4713
1507231.5  bad input    7/30/-586  bad input
1721420    12/26/-1     12/28/0    12/26/0
1721425    12/31/-1     1/2/1      12/31/0
1741426    10/5/55      10/7/55    10/5/55
2222444    9/28/1372    9/20/1372  9/28/1372
2299160    10/14/1582   10/4/1582  10/14/1582
2299161    10/15/1582   10/15/1582 10/15/1582
2399301.5  bad input    12/18/1856 bad input
2422444    4/29/1920    4/29/1920  4/29/1920
```

Comment: Just to clarify, Meeus and Richards have different starting years?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a starting year. JD 0.0 is noon, January 1, 4713 BC, Julian calendar. Both Meeus' and Richards' algorithms work for this date; Meeus gives output "1/1/-4712" [Julian calendar] and Richards gives output "11/25/-4713" [Gregorian calendar], which is in keeping with their recognition of year 0, which necessitates reducing the absolute value of a BC date by 1 when changing to the negative sign or 0 notation. Meeus said his algorithm is only valid for non-negative Julian days; Richards did not state the earliest date for which his algorithm works.

Comment: Just to clarify.  Meeus is an astronomer and presents his calculation with a year 0 - that is between -1 and 1 there is a year 0, however, since calendrical calculations ignore this 0 = 1 BCE hence Meeus is correct -4712 = 4713 BCE, However Richards is wrong if there is a year 0, but you have said that Richards ignores the year 0 in which case, -4713 is rendered 4713 BCE.  That is what I've gathered, this is not explicit in Meeus at all and is very confusing.  The result is that Meeus' calculations are for astronomers and they don't care too much about historical calendar dates.

Comment: I wrote "Richards considers the year 0 to exist and always converts to Gregorian." Richards algorithm gives correct results in terms of the convention that there is a year 0 between -1 and 1. For example, for JD 0, the Richards algorithm gives 11/24/-4713 Gregorian calendar, which is November 24, 4714 BC, and which can be confirmed at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_extns_templ_patterns_date_time_conv.html In the comment above I copied the wrong line and mistakenly put "11/25/-4713" for JD 0 when it's really ""11/24/-4713"

Comment: I would also add that I've never seen a historian write a negative sign before a year. I very much doubt you will find a historical publication state it is acceptable to simply replace the characters "BC" with the character "-". Astronomers have been using the convention that there is a year 0 when using signed year numbers for centuries. Astronomers drop the year 0 when using AD/BC notation just like the historians. It is only the computer programming community that has used the convention that there is no year 0 when using signed numbers.

Comment: The negative sign is used for calculations.  It is not replacable by simply adding BCE, rather the formula -n = n+1 BC/BCE is required.

Comment: So let us clarify Richards starting point (JD = 0) is 1/1/-4713 (= 24 Nov 4714 BCE Gregorian)
Meeus’ algorithm doesn’t work for Julian dates before 0 (1 BCE Julian) So the algorithm is simply irrelevant prior.  Thanks for the clarification.  
PHP’s algorithm conforms to Richard past Gregorian dates > 0, PHP prior to 0 and 0 converts 0 to -1 and then ends up with -4714 as the starting year (Without the need to add an extra year for BC conversion since I guess Gregorian dates are dates and not integers.  Richards does not do that and leaves the the year 0 in

Comment: To convert from signed notation to BCE/CE notation, or equivalently, BC/AD notation, -n = n+1 BCE for Meeus, Richards, astronomers in general, ISO 8601:2004, and XSD 1.1, . The internal PHP function uses the conversion -n = n BCE, as do XSD 1.0 and ISO 8601:1988.

Comment: "Meeus’ algorithm doesn’t work for Julian dates before 0 (1 BCE Julian)". No, Meeus states his algorithm isn't valid for negative Julian DAYS. This means Meeus does not guarantee the algorithm for a date/time less than January 1, 4713 BC, 12:00 UT. The earliest JD that the PHP function works for is 1, which gives the output 11/25/-4714, which means November 25, 4714 BCE. If you input JD 0 into the PHP function the output is 0/0/0 which is obviously invalid.

Comment: Meeus’ years before 0 is therefore year - 1 because he ignores 0?

So php is technically correct if you correct for ISO 8601:1988 
4714 BCE = -4713 (which in PHP is listed as -4714)
and Meeus is wrong according to ISO 8601 and needs to be adjusted for values before AD 1.

Comment: Meeus doesn't ignore 0, he recognizes 0. ISO 8601:1988 would write 4714 BCE as -4714. ISO 8601:2004, the current version, would write 4714 BCE as -4713. Meeus agrees with ISO 8601:2004.

Comment: so why is the output -4712?

Comment: Meeus uses 0 and then gets the start JD=1 as -4712 either its 4714 BCE = -4713 but its not -4712 or 4713 BCE

Comment: Meeus gives JD 1 as 1/2/-4712 which is January 2, 4713 BC, JULIAN CALENDAR. Richards gives 11/25/-4713, which is November 25, 4714 BC GREGORIAN CALENDAR. There was a 37 day difference in the calendars back then, with the Gregorian calendar nominally being earlier. (Of course, physically, they were the same day.)

Comment: I got it now, so in the case of the starting point, Gregorian is a year EARLIER!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing as a Gregorian year 0 because the Gregorian calendar didn't start until 1582. Astronomical algorithms use the Julian calendar before Gregorian calendar reform. Yes astronomical algorithms return a year zero. Meeus is absolutely correct. -years are NOT the same as BC years. Look it up. Any algorithm that uses BC-AD is using the entirely fictitious proleptic Gregorian calendar which is not used by astronomers. Look it up.

Comment: Which books have you cited to look it up in? Actually, the historical Gregorian Calendar goes back to 1582 for Catholic Europe, 1752 for the British Commonwealth, 1792? (I know it was after the French Revolution) for the French, and the Russians after 1923?  If you read the question carefully, you would have found that the issue was with proleptic calendars and their translation into common nomenclature. If outputted the test data you would have found some non-correlations. Meeus' algorithm does not work for year < 0 (Julian).  So Meeus is only technically right in a particular use case.

Comment: I would like to add that PHP does not use a worthless algorithm.  I think you should do us all a favor and cite the literature that shows which algorithm was chosen and why.  Who are you to tell the creators of PHP that their choice of algorithms is "worthless"?

Comment: The proleptic Gregorian calendar is not used by astronomers and books about astronomical algorithms don't even acknowledge its existence. Meeus' algorithm actually does work for negative years with my C compiler but if you have any doubts, use another one like the method of Peter Baum. Who do I think I am to question the all poewerfull PHP?

Comment: The proleptic Gregorian date of JD 1099114.5 should be 3/4/-1703 so the PHP function seems to use the proleptic Gregorian calendar but return incorrect results.

Comment: You write: "The proleptic Gregorian calendar is not used by astronomers and books about astronomical algorithms don't even acknowledge its existence."  Prove it! There are a good many historical and professional astronomers that are interested in this sort of thing, consider N Dershowitz and Reingold's Calendricsl Calculations 3rd Ed. CUP.  In any event I don't really care what your opinion is. It does exist and is a useful reference point for date conversions (see above citation). Your point is not relevant.  Whether Meeus uses it or not was a question I had and was already answered.

Comment: Also, at this point, you have to *prove* it is buggy.  Gerard Ashton has pointed out dates are interpreted and therefore one has to be careful of the actual documentation surrounding implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
void JDToDateMeeus(double jDNum, int *month, double *day, int *year) //converts a Julian day to a calendar Date
{
int alpha, A, B, C, D, E, Z;
double F;

jDNum += 0.5;
Z = jDNum;  //Z == int so I = int part
F = jDNum - Z;  //F =  fractional part
if(Z < 2299161)  //Julian?
    A = Z;
else{  //Gregorian
    alpha = (int)floor((Z - 1867216.25) / 36524.25);
    A = Z + 1 + alpha - (int)floor(alpha / 4.0);
    }
B = A + 1524;
C = (int)floor((B - 122.1) /365.25);
D = (int)floor(365.25 * C);
E = (int)floor((B - D) /30.6001);
*day = B - D - (int)floor(30.6001 * E) + F;
if( E < 14)
    *month = E - 1;
else
    *month = E - 13;
if(*month > 2)
    *year = C - 4716;
else
    *year = C - 4715;
}

double DateToJulianDayNumber(int month, double day, int year) //after Meeus
{
int  M, Y, A, B;
double JD;

if(month > 2){
    Y = year;
    M = month;
    }
else{
    Y = year - 1;
    M = month + 12;
    }
if((year > 1582) || ((year == 1582) && ((month == 10 && day >= 5.0) || (month > 10)))){ //Gregorian
    A = (int)floor(Y / 100.0);
    B = 2 - A + (int)floor(A / 4.0);
    }
else
    B = 0;
JD = (int)floor(365.25 * (Y + 4716)) + (int)floor(30.6001 * (M + 1)) + day + B - 1524.5;
return JD;
}
```

These functions don't use the fictitious proleptic Gregorian calendar. October 4th is followed by the 15th in 1582 as per Pope Gregory's calendar reform. Uses Gregorian leap years after 1582. There is a year 0 and years before that are written with a minus sign.

Comment: Astronomers describe a time of observation as a number of days and a fraction of a day from a fundamental epoch. They chose noon January 1st, -4712 Greenwich Mean Time. The Julian day starts at noon because they were interested in things that were visible at night. The number of days and fraction of a day elapsed since this time is a Julian day. The whole number of days elapsed since this time is a Julian day number. Calendar conversions are based on Julian days. A source calendar date is converted to a Julian day and the Julian day is converted to the target calendar.

Comment: I am well aware of this. Also, the proleptic Gregorian calendar makes perfect sense, it just means that documents prior to Oct 4th 1582 have to be converted from Julian to Gregorian if you want to know what time of year they were dealing with from our perspective.  The Julian Calendar (in use before the Gregorian Switch), does not have a year 0 and so mathematically year 0 = -1 BC.  Also, your formula has no relevance to countries who changed over in 1752. Nonetheless, thanks for providing a formula for Meeus' Algorithm.  The question was also how other algorithms stack up against my formulae.

Comment: Your code is written in C/C++ not much help to the question which was asked for PHP

Comment: Actually FYI acc. to this article https://dev.to/mporam/is-php-relevant--1np PHP covers 83% of the market-share of internet-based languages (I might add server-side).  Tech Republic lists PHP as no. 6 to learn (just below C) (https://www.techrepublic.com/article/7-programming-languages-that-every-developer-should-learn-in-2018/). There are already Astro libraries for the top listed languages (Java, Javascript, Python and C).  And a simple date calculator is not "many types of astronomy-based calculations).

Comment: Every language has to be evaluated as the right tool for the job given particular criteria, feasibility, and cost-time factor evaluation.  It is not up to you to decide what should or should not be done with PHP.  The question was explicitly referring to PHP and not C/C++.

Answer (score -2):

I used below php code to convert julian date to gregorian format.

```php
$ts=mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 136, "20" . 20);

$mydate=date ('m-d-Y', $ts);

echo $mydate;
```

You can also refer to https://www.juliandate.net to convert the dates.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, while this may answer the question, it is better to give explanations and not only code for your answer.

Comment: Hi, please enclose the code inside triple quotes like this to so that it is easily understandable:

```
code

```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I think you need review what I wrote in the question.  The Julian Date referenced in my question refers to Scaliger's number (Julian date) as cited in the Astronomical Almanac.  Additionally, I cited 4 different algorithms, by 4 different reputable sources, with use-case data.  The "Julian Date" to which you refer has nothing to do with astronomy, but the implementation of "Ordinal Date" which refers to how mainframes store dates in the format "yyddd" where the "ddd" is a number from 1-366 depending on the day number in the year in question.

Comment: The reference you cited says the same thing.  Consider @Gerard Ashton's answer above and the discussion we had. A superb answer that clarified many important points.